# Chart.js nuget Package with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, charts, chart.js

Can someone point me to a good documentation on how I can use the Nuget package Chart.js I installed in one of my .Net projects that uses AngularJS. The documentation on Chart.js on the net sets the charts with jQuery, I need to use the angularJS controller approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Chart.js doesn't deal with any Angular data binding, you can refer to this third party directives; ["angular-chart.js - beautiful, reactive, responsive charts for Angular.JS using Chart.js"](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to integrate Chart.js with Angular.

Comment: Thanks Rebornix. I tried that and added angular-chart to my Scripts, added a link in my index.html and added a reference to Chart.js in my app.js. I get the following error in angular-chart.js "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Chart' is undefined". Any clue what I could be missing.

Comment: I suppose it might be an initialization sequence issue. Do you reference chart.js before angular-chart.js?

Comment: You were correct, I had missed the Chart.js reference in my index.html. I am able to add charts on the page now. Thanks for the help. Any idea how I can implement 3D charts?